# Description of tag badges.

Tags: support, badges

Earned at least $x$ total score for at least $y$ answers in the $z$ tag.

How can I know how much have I constituted in any tag, and also where can I find the description of these badges.

Help appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Go to the "Tags" section of your profile.

> [image]

Put your cursor over each number to see your activity within that tag.

> [image]

All badge descriptions are available on the tab that says "Badges" at the top of the site:

> [image]

[Here is a link to them](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/badges).